# Type T parameters not the same

Tags: java, generics

I have the following code:

```
  public static <T> T print(T element1, T element2){
        System.out.println(element1.getClass());
        System.out.println(element2.getClass());
        return null;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        print(10, "str");
    }
```

It compiles, no errors. Method "print" accepts two arguments of the same Type (T). But I can call this method, for example, with Integer and String arguments.

If I want to use return value, code doesn't compile:

```
Integer t = print(10, 20.0); //compilation error
```

This example also has the same behavior. I can use different types for Array and for Element (but if I use different types, I get ArrayStoreException).

```
 public static <T> void fillArray(T[] array, T element){}
```

And if I work with Collections, I can't use different types. The following example doesnt compile:

```
 public static <T> void fillList(List<T> list, T element){}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        fillList(list, 20.0);
    }
```

What's the reason of such behavior? Why I can call method with different types with Arrays, and cannot with Lists, if I declared, that I have only the same type T?

Comment: looks like calling it with Integer and String is just using T as an Object. So you should be able to call it Object t = print(10, 20.0);

Comment: Yes, I understand it. But why I can call "print" with different types, if I declared, that I have only one type T?

Answer (score 0):

Where it works, you didn't specify the return type, so the compiler can use the most generic one (`Object`).

As soon as you declare the return type (that has to be the same as the type of the passed parameters), you cannot mix.

Actually you also don't mix at the place where it works, the compiler just uses `Object` everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

It works even when you use the return value, but you have to specify the correct return type, i.e. the type which is common to both parameters. `Integer` and `String` both share the supertype `Object`, and as such they can be considered to be of "same type". `Object` is the common base type of all other types. For numbers, `Number` could work as well:

```
Number t = print(10, 20.0);
Object o = print("string", 12.3);
```